# Изучаю JS для веб разработки.Запутался что мне нужно читать

Tags: javascript, frontend

В общем читаю "Язык JavaScript" часть 1 автор Илья Кантор 2015 год выпуска. Но там вроде  нету ничего связаного с веб (у меня книга в пдф формате там 3246 страниц и я сейчас на 744).В содержании по сути основы  js (в общем основное внимание уделяться именно самому языку JavaScript).

Но я посмотрел содержание второй части, там уже есть js для веб (Окружение: DOM, BOM и JS).Проблема моя в чем.Я вот смотрю в интернете как делают разные слайдеры формы и т.д  используя js и используют такиу команды как `getElementById` и т.д. Но про них рассказывают во 2 части книги. И у меня возникает вопрос -  нужно ли мне полностью проходить весь материал 1 части или можно выучить самое основное и уже глубже разбираться  с js в веб разработке?

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, содержание 1 части и подскажите что к чему?

Comment: Однозначно весь материал. Там не так уж и много. Фреймворков нет, Node.JS отсутствует и т.д. Хотя там скринкасты есть хорошие, однозначно рекомендую.

Comment: @BogdanBida я ушел далеко не прочитав не одной книги по js

Answer (score 5):

Практика это конечно очень и очень важно, но читать тоже нужно) посоветую вам то, что сам сейчас использую при изучении JavaScript - это сайт W3schools, где минимум информации а главное есть наглядные примеры, поэтому можно все очень хорошо понять. А учебники лично мне всякие никогда не давались ибо пишется там как то субьективно и в основном уже очень детализировано, что просто отпугивает новичков. Это вам не нужно - лучше юзайте сайт что я написал (там не только JS есть:) и пишите параллельно для закрепления, как бы не было лень)

Comment: w3shools местами содержит устаревшую и/или ложную информацию (видимо, поэтому, в западном сообществе SO его частенько называют w3fools). Разумнее будет использовать и рекомендовать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/ как более авторитетный источник.

Comment: @yar85, да там не местами... А даже частенько встречал... Щас не приведу пример, давно использовал...  Может даже исправили...

Comment: @yar85 тогда по этой логике книжка вообще беда, верно?)

Comment: @Geri4, если под логикой подразумевается принцип "сразу получать актуальную инфу, не тратя время на устаревшую", то верно. Общие основы программирования можно (и наверное, нужно) получить из книг, так как эти основы не особо меняются со временем... а вот живые ЯП, лучше изучать по обновляемой документации, имхо.

Comment: @yar85, ну я такого не заметил, сайт просто находка, все новые версии и новшества HTML5 и CSS3 расписаны с примерами, js также, по фреймворкам не знаю, еще перед этим freecodecamp юзал по верстке, но там пока мало уроков, хотя если реализуют задуманное все, то будет еще один отличнейший сервис для обучения на практике)

Answer (score -1):

1. Если ты не умеешь прогать - читай полностью, ибо без основ далеко не уйдешь.
2. Если ты основы знаешь(циклы, массивы и тп), то можешь вообще не читать, прогать нужно учиться только на практике, ты можешь прочитать много книг и не уметь прогать(зато собеседования пройдешь на изи(: ), и не прочитав не одну быть топчиком=)
3. Мое мнение что книги имеет смысл читать только так - прочел -> применил НА РЕАЛЬНОЙ ЗАДАЧЕ. Книги хороши когда ты уже умеешь.
   PS. js сам по себе очень простой язык 2е книги по 3000 страниц каждая, мягко говоря перебор...